# What is muieblackcat?

Tags: security, iis

I've recently installed ELMAH on a small .NET MVC site and I keep receiving error reports

```
System.Web.HttpException: A public action method 'muieblackcat' was not found on controller...
```

This is obviously an attempt to access a page that doesn't exist.  But why are there attempts to access this page?

Is this an attack or is it simply a bot scanning to see if I've been infected?  What exactly is 'muieblackcat' and why is there an attempt to access this URL?

Comment: FYI muie means blowjob in Romanian.

Answer (score 26):

It is just a hole finder script. The requests made are typically the following ones, if your servers answers all with a 404 error, you do not have anything to worry about.

```
111.221.1.140 - - [20/Nov/2013:10:15:56 +0000] "GET //xampp/phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1787 "-" "-"
111.221.1.140 - - [20/Nov/2013:10:15:55 +0000] "GET //websql/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1787 "-" "-"
111.221.1.140 - - [20/Nov/2013:10:15:55 +0000] "GET //web/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1787 "-" "-"
111.221.1.140 - - [20/Nov/2013:10:15:54 +0000] "GET //web/phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1787 "-" "-"
111.221.1.140 - - [20/Nov/2013:10:15:53 +0000] "GET //typo3/phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1787 "-" "-"
111.221.1.140 - - [20/Nov/2013:10:15:51 +0000] "GET //scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1787 "-" "-"
111.221.1.140 - - [20/Nov/2013:10:15:50 +0000] "GET //pma/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1787 "-" "-"
111.221.1.140 - - [20/Nov/2013:10:15:49 +0000] "GET //phpmyadmin2/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1787 "-" "-"
111.221.1.140 - - [20/Nov/2013:10:15:48 +0000] "GET //phpmyadmin1/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1787 "-" "-"
111.221.1.140 - - [20/Nov/2013:10:15:47 +0000] "GET //phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1787 "-" "-"
111.221.1.140 - - [20/Nov/2013:10:15:47 +0000] "GET //phpadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1787 "-" "-"
111.221.1.140 - - [20/Nov/2013:10:15:46 +0000] "GET //phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1787 "-" "-"
111.221.1.140 - - [20/Nov/2013:10:15:45 +0000] "GET //phpMyAdmin-2/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1787 "-" "-"
111.221.1.140 - - [20/Nov/2013:10:15:44 +0000] "GET //phpMyAdmin-2.5.5/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1787 "-" "-"
111.221.1.140 - - [20/Nov/2013:10:15:44 +0000] "GET //phpMyAdmin-2.5.5-pl1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1787 "-" "-"
111.221.1.140 - - [20/Nov/2013:10:15:43 +0000] "GET //php-my-admin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1787 "-" "-"
111.221.1.140 - - [20/Nov/2013:10:15:42 +0000] "GET //mysqladmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1787 "-" "-"
111.221.1.140 - - [20/Nov/2013:10:15:41 +0000] "GET //mysql/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1787 "-" "-"
111.221.1.140 - - [20/Nov/2013:10:15:41 +0000] "GET //myadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1787 "-" "-"
111.221.1.140 - - [20/Nov/2013:10:15:40 +0000] "GET //dbadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1787 "-" "-"
111.221.1.140 - - [20/Nov/2013:10:15:39 +0000] "GET //db/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1787 "-" "-"
111.221.1.140 - - [20/Nov/2013:10:15:38 +0000] "GET //admin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1787 "-" "-"
111.221.1.140 - - [20/Nov/2013:10:15:37 +0000] "GET //admin/pma/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1787 "-" "-"
111.221.1.140 - - [20/Nov/2013:10:15:36 +0000] "GET //admin/phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1787 "-" "-"
111.221.1.140 - - [20/Nov/2013:10:15:35 +0000] "GET //MyAdmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1787 "-" "-"
111.221.1.140 - - [20/Nov/2013:10:15:34 +0000] "GET /muieblackcat HTTP/1.1" 404 1787 "-" "-"
```

Comment: Agree. Im watching that right now and sending a report to abuse emai.
My next step is a csf script that does it for me.

I will spam abuse emails on each attack :D

Answer (score 10):

muieblackcat is script/bot, supposedly of Ukrainian origin, that attempts to exploit PHP vulnerabilities or misconfigurations. See *[SUC027: Muieblackcat setup.php Web Scanner/Robot](http://eromang.zataz.com/2011/08/14/suc027-muieblackcat-setup-php-web-scanner-robot/)* for more detail.

If you are not using PHP and have deactivated [mod_php](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Usage), you're safe. However, a request for
/muieblackcat may mean that the bot has already, maybe successfully, visited your site. I
suggest you carefully check your configuration and web content (if possible, erase all and reinstall
from a trusted source set).

On the other hand, the originating IP address is likely to be useless. Most attacks come
from unaware infected Windows users.

Comment: Why would you want to reinstall?

Comment: Because it can be difficult to make sure there are absolutely no traces left after a cleanup, and only one overlooked php file is all it needs to resurrect. Wiping the installation and restore from known-good will be more thorough.

Answer (score 4):

I do it another way - redirect them on theirs IP on the same URI. Somethig like this:

```
redirect301 = http://hackerIP/muieblackcat
```

I think it's easier for the server to send a 301 redirect than to return a 404 page each time.

Answer (score 3):

According to *[Daily Update Summary 6/24/2011](http://www.emergingthreatspro.com/ruleset-update/daily-update-summary-6242011/)* (*Emerging Threat Pro* blog), it's a scanner which is looking for some breaches in your server; it's definitely an intruder that you should block. Look for your access logs, you should get its IP address.

Comment: Why block them? It's a free pentest. Use the attack profile to enhance your security. They're going to have a new IP 5 minutes from now anyway. ;)